# Finding g(x) in acceptance-rejection method

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, simulation

I am having a hard time finding an appropriate g(x) to simulate my f(x) using acceptance-rejection method.
[image: a busy cat]

Also, what would be the logic behind how to find a g(x)? Like I know it has to have the same range as f(x) but are there any other restrictions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to add the self study tag.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by 'the' rejection method? There are several rejection methods. One would be to generate 2 standard exponentials, at random use just one half of the time and the sum of both the rest of the time. [Your $X$ is a 50-50 mixture of std exponential and gamma with shape param 2.] // (2) If you are looking for a 'majorizing function' $g(x)$ of $f(x),$ then $g(x)$ should be the density of something easy to simulate and you need to find a constant $K$ such that $Kg(x) \ge f(x),$ for all $x$ in the support of $f(x).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $Y+1 \sim \text{Ga}(2,1)$ then the random variable $Y$ has the density function:

$$g(y) = \text{Ga}(y+1|2,1) = \frac{1}{e} \cdot (1+y) e^{-y}
\quad \quad \quad
\text{for all } -1 < y < \infty.$$

This density function bears a striking resemblance to the target distribution.  Have a think about how you might use this result, in conjunction with a rejection step, to obtain a value from the target distribution.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment (1) continued:* The following R code 'wastes' a quarter of the exponentials and that waste could be eliminated with some care. Not even sure if this satisfies your definition of Accept-Reject.

```
set.seed(729);  m = 10^6
u1 = runif(m);  u2 = runif(m);  u3 = runif(m)    # 3 std uniforma
v1 = -log(u1);  v2 = -log(u2)                    # 2 std exponentials
s = (u3 < 1/2);  x = v1 + s*v2                   # Acc or Rej 2nd
hist(x, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main="")  # Illustrating fit to ...
curve((1+x)*exp(-x)/2, add=T, col="red", lwd=2)  # ... target density
```

[image]